# Flutter IOS - device not supported on Iphone 15 / IOS 17

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, ios17

I am developing an application with flutter and when my client tries to install it on Iphone 15 / IOS 17, he cannot do it with the error "Device not supported".
[Device not supported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zzQ.png)

Here is my configuration in xcode:
[config xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3baN.png)

Do you have any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you share the minimum deployments you set? It can be found under the Target, inside General.

Comment: @tomerpacific IOS11

Comment: And which Xcode version did you use to build the application?

Comment: @tomerpacific Xcode 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the device is not supported is due to the XCode version you are using to build and deploy your iOS application. As mentioned in the comments, you are using XCode version 13.2.1. If you look [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/), you will be able to see that the OS version and device are not supported by it.

[image: Screenshot]

If you want to support iPhone 15 with OS 17, you will need to upgrade your XCode to at least XCode 15.

[image: Screenshot 2]

**[FYI, since April 25, 2023, all applications submitted to the App Store, must be build by XCode 14.1 or later](https://developer.apple.com/news/upcoming-requirements/?id=04252023a)**